# Get error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved when i want edit pod with kubectl edit

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

When i want to edit my deployment pod with kubectl edit deployment [name] command i got this error. whats the problem?!

[image]

i found this: You cant edit the pod. You can edit only deployment. If you want to change anything in pod, you need to take a pod yaml output and then update your changes and recreate the pod.

how can i do that?

Comment: Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the object manifest that you first used to deploy that object. If you're using a Pod object such as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

edit this YAML and redeploy. The reason as to why you can't edit the *deployed* pod (i.e. the pod listed from `kubectl get po`) is because pods are ephemeral, they an be killed and restarted for any reason. If you *could* edit a deployed pod, if for any reason, the pod terminates, you're changes are gone. That's why you edit through the YAML/Object manifest which is your source of truth (desired state).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The problem was when I tried to edit image and change the version kubectl editor added a tab, and changed indentation..
When I removed the tab it accepted the change

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
```

As soon as I started to add the version indent changed:

```
spec:
  containers:
        - image: nginx:1.16
*error: unknown command "nginx-deply image nginx:1.16"*
```

After removing the 'extra' tab:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.16
 *deployment.apps/nginx-deply edited*
```